# Xcode 11 - is the Main Storyboard the same thing as Launch scree storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcode 11 - is the Main Storyboard the same thing as Launch scree storyboard? Do I have to create another MainStory board to start creating my application? I am comparing this to Xcode 7. Slightly confused.

Comment: No, the main storyboard and launch storyboards are separate.  If you create a new project in Xcode using one of the templates it will create both, unless you select "SwiftUI" in which case there is no main storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

> Is the Main Storyboard the same thing as Launch scree storyboard?

**Launch screen** storyboard is different from your other storyboards, like your **Main**. Although they are technically same kind of file.

In **Launch screen** storyboard, you can't assign custom class.

> Do I have to create another MainStory board to start creating my
>   application?

When building applications with both **SwiftUI and UIKit**, setting up **Launch screen** storyboard is the same thing.

You don't have to create another storyboard IF you are using **SwiftUI**.